# What do you call those films with nudity, if not pornographic scenes, but not marketed as porn?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Probably has the same audience as porn but instead has mainstream studio producers and full-length cinema release.

Comment: Adult films or blue films, perhaps.

Comment: Erotic thriller?

Comment: Please provide the title of such a film. It could be sexy/nude film or movie, it might even be called X rated by some

Comment: Movies that include nudity but do not include pornographic scenes and are not marketed as porn are generally called "movies." Or maybe 
"R-rated movies."

Comment: Uh, we call them *films*? Are you suggesting there should be a single word for any film that shows a naked human body?

Comment: Those are just called ***R-rated*** films.

Comment: Usually, if it ain't porn but somebody wants to call it that, the term is 'erotica'. Nothing wrong with nudity that I know of, except in certain environments--too much sun, too cold, places full of prudes, etc. Anyway, I voted to close because I can't make out your question.

Comment: Two fairly commonly used terms are "[exploitation film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploitation_film)" (a very general category that covers—or uncovers—various types of lurid content) and "[sexploitation film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexploitation_film)," aka "soft-core," a genre that (as the Wikipedia article points out) is characterized primarily by gratuitous nudity. _Gratuitous_ in this context means not serving any practical purpose in moving the plot forward (assuming that there is a plot).

Answer (score 2):

***[Softcore porn movies](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softcore_pornography):***

> - Softcore pornography or softcore porn is commercial still photography or film that has a pornographic or erotic component. It is less sexually graphic and intrusive than hardcore pornography. ***It typically contains nude or semi-nude actors involved in love scenes, and is intended to be sexually arousing and aesthetically beautiful.***

(Wikipedia)

Comment: The thing is, softcore movies are not produced by mainstream studios, and generally softcore porn and hardcore porn do not share the same audience. This may be the answer the OP is looking for, but it certainly doesn't fit the criteria that has been included.